# How many ways can $3$ regular polygons meet at a vertex?

Tags: geometry, diophantine-equations, polygons

This is equivalent to  the positive integer solutions to $$\frac{a-2}{a} + \frac{b-2}{b} + \frac{c-2}{c} = 2$$ with $3 \le a \le b \le c$.

Small solutions like $(6, 6, 6)$ and $(4, 8, 8)$ can be guessed, but other solutions such as $(4, 5, 20)$ exist.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, basically ${1\over a}+{1\over b} +{1\over c}={1\over2}$ is what you want.

Let $a\geq b\geq c$ we know since ${({1\over2})\over3}={1\over6}$, ${1\over c}\geq{1\over6}$ and hence $c\leq 6$.

This leaves us four possibilities.

(1) $c=3$ then ${1\over a}+{1\over b}={1\over 6}\implies ab=6a+6b\implies (a-6)(b-6)=36$

(2) $c=4$ then ${1\over a}+{1\over b}={1\over 4}\implies ab=4a+4b\implies (a-4)(b-4)=16$

(3) $c=5$ then ${1\over a}+{1\over b}={3\over 10}\implies 3ab=10a+10b\implies (3a-10)(3b-10)=100$

(4) $c=6$ then ${1\over a}+{1\over b}={1\over 3}\implies ab=3a+3b\implies (a-3)(b-3)=9$

Comment: Following croo1's method you must be getting: $$(a,b,c)=(3,7,42):(3,8,24):(3,9,18):(3,10,15):(3,12,12):(4,5,20):(4,6,12):(4,8,8):(5,5,10):(6,6,6).$$

Comment: The question can be recast as the $n = 8$ case of the Erdos-Straus conjecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture and is known to have 6 solutions with $a \neq b\neq c$.

Comment: @WillieWong: Sorry I meant (5,5,10).