# Ways to place regular polygons around a planar vertex

Tags: geometry, alternative-proof, polygons

I am interested in the following question:

> What are all the ways to completely fill a planar vertex using convex regular polygons?

For example if you place 2 squares and 3 equilateral triangles around a vertex their interal angles add to $2\pi$ and that vertex is filled.  Using the fact the internal angle of a regular polygon with $n$ sides is $\pi\frac{n-2}{n}$ we can restate this as:

> How many multi-sets $A$ (of integers greater than 2) satisfy:
> $$
> 2=\sum_{n\in A}\frac{n-2}{n}
> $$

<sup>(Note that because $A$ is a multi-set we are not counting different ways of arranging the same polygons separately. It's fairly trivial once you have this classification to enumerate the arrangements via necklaces.)</sup>

I took a bit of time and just came up with as many as I could before I felt like it seemed complete:

$$
3,3,3,3,3,3\\
4,4,3,3,3\\
4,4,4,4\\
6,3,3,3,3\\
6,6,3,3\\
6,6,6\\
8,8,4\\
10,5,5\\
12,4,3,3\\
12,6,4\\
12,12,3\\
15,10,3\\
18,9,3\\
20,5,4\\
24,8,3\\
42,7,3\\
$$

From here I proved two fairly trivial facts:

- Solutions must have between 3 and 6 polygons.
- Solutions cannot have two values both greater than 12.

With this the search space is finite and I ran a [computer search](https://tio.run/##dZExb4MwEIV3/4o30AiKQIGqSxSYOrZLV2RFbmMlVrGNjEOX/Hd6dghqh1ryyfre893Zdxbjl@z7eVZ6sM7jRXhRvguvLPtNXtXoGfu0euill5jQMICOFAFvvegjCatGgfGi0SE1RZ3hAQZX2vsCE48es3rNRUsnvHW3HJEeV/UojdXK/NGViWJHth21cV2Kt9his4HJazQNaRx5vhjrx3@sVbRyxk7ShC5kLHyyqGps6fR9lk7GJMQOeF776jrO79xAowmE8mvKXYXKONrFqsKzuyeUJQxfWKp2GfZJG64rpDqvslkLdfsVLYa3AwanjEdC//NBcQxjSIKE1MlJulGijDQjvHbftg3uE5p/AA).  It found a solution I missed:

$$
6,4,4,3
$$

I felt a little silly about missing this, but that gives the complete list. However I don't think I'm alone in finding "I had a computer check all 2992 possibilities and it came up with this complete list" very satisfying as a proof.

Is there a way to prove the correct list is complete in a size that would be feasible for a human to verify on paper?

Comment: I think the work you did shows it is feasible to do with paper, you just have to do it right.  Like the computer program it is exhausting the possibilities so I am not sure it is any more satisfying.  I don't mind a proof of this style.

Comment: You may be finding all the "plane-vertex tilings", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_tilings_by_convex_regular_polygons#Plane-vertex_tilings

Comment: By the way, have you looked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523647/how-many-ways-can-3-regular-polygons-meet-at-a-vertex

Comment: Even better, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3304309/counting-how-many-regular-polygons-combinations-can-form-360-degrees-around-a-po

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting how many regular polygons combinations can form 360 degrees around a point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3304309/counting-how-many-regular-polygons-combinations-can-form-360-degrees-around-a-po)

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm sorry.  I try not to leave comments like "Thank you" which don't provide any additional content.  Instead I just upvote comments I find useful.  Both the linked questions appeared in the similar tab when I was writing this and I have read them both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'll take it up at the point of finding all solutions, by hand, to
$$
{a_1-2\over a_1}+{a_2-2\over a_2}+\cdots+{a_r-2\over a_r}=2, 
$$
with $3\le a_1\le a_2\le\cdots\le a_r$, $r\ge3$.

With a little bit of algebra, we can rewrite this as
$$
{1\over a_1}+{1\over a_2}+\cdots+{1\over a_r}={r-2\over2}
$$

Case 1: $r=3$. Changing notation a bit, we have
$$
{1\over a}+{1\over b}+{1\over c}={1\over2},
$$
with $3\le a\le b\le c$.

If $a\ge7$, then the left side is at most $3/7$, which is less than $1/2$, so $3\le a\le6$.

If $a=6$, we must have $a=b=c=6$ (here and elsewhere I will leave out detailed justifications when I think it should be obvious how to do them), so we get the solution
$$
6,6,6
$$

If $a=5$, we get
$$
{1\over b}+{1\over c}={3\over10}.
$$
Then $1/b\ge (1/2)(3/10)=3/20$, so $b\le20/3$, so $b=5$ or $b=6$. $b=5$ leads to $c=10$, so we get
$$
5,5,10
$$
$b=6$ does not yield an integer for $c$. So, that completes $a=5$.

If $a=4$, we have
$$
{1\over b}+{1\over c}={1\over4},
$$
so $4\le b\le8$. Trying each of these values of $b$ in turn, we get
$$
\matrix{4,5,20\cr4,6,12\cr4,8,8\cr}
$$

If $a=3$, then
$$
{1\over b}+{1\over c}={1\over6},
$$
from which $7\le b\le12$. Trying each value of $b$ in turn, we find
$$
\matrix{3,7,42\cr3,8,24\cr3,9,18\cr3,10,15\cr3,12,12\cr}
$$

That completes the case $r=3$.

Case 2: $r=4$. We need
$$
{1\over a}+{1\over b}+{1\over c}+{1\over d}=1
$$
with $3\le a\le b\le c\le d$. Also, $a\le4$.

If $a=4$, then $a=b=c=d=4$, and we get
$$
4,4,4,4
$$

If $a=3$, then
$$
{1\over b}+{1\over c}+{1\over d}={2\over3}
$$
$3/5<2/3$, so $3\le b\le4$.

$b=4$ gives
$$
{1\over c}+{1\over d}={5\over12}
$$
where the only solution is $c=4$, $d=6$, so we get
$$
3,4,4,6
$$
$b=3$ gives
$$
{1\over c}+{1\over d}={1\over3}
$$
which leads to $c=4$, $d=12$ and $c=d=6$. Thus,
$$
\matrix{3,3,4,12\cr3,3,6,6\cr}
$$
That completes Case 2.

Case 3: $r=5$.
$$
{1\over a}+\cdots+{1\over e}={3\over2}
$$
$5/4<3/2$, so $a=3$. $4/4<7/6$, so $b=3$. $3/4<5/6$, so $c=3$. So we are down to
$$
{1\over d}+{1\over e}={1\over2}
$$
which has solutions $d=3$, $e=6$ and $d=e=4$. So we get
$$
\matrix{3,3,3,3,6\cr3,3,3,4,4\cr}
$$
That does Case 3.

Case 4: $r=6$,
$$
{1\over a}+\cdots+{1\over f}=2
$$
We have $3\le a\le\cdots\le f$, but $a=\cdots=f=3$ is a solution, so it is the only solution:
$$
3,3,3,3,3,3
$$
and we're done.